# Javascript - Dynamic variable

Tags: javascript

I am having problem to figure correct syntax to make those Javascript dynamic variable works:

I want to replace this code:

```
<code>
    var res1 = res0.replace('[a1]', a1);
    var res2 = res1.replace('[a2]', a2);
    (...)
    var res7 = res6.replace('[a7]', a7);
</code>
```

With something dynamic, like

```
<code>
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    **var str2 ="res" + i + " = res + i + .replace('[a + 'i']', window['a' + i])";**
    eval(str2);
}
</code>
```

The ElementID is recovered from another Dynamic Variable, that works

```
<code>
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        var str ="a" + i + " = document.getElementById('a'+i).value";
        eval(str);
    }
</code>
```

General idea is simple.
Capture from a form, (input type text) and replace the strings called [a1], [a2], etc inside a textarea. Code works without dynamic variables.

Any idea is more than welcome.

Thank you

Comment: What is `res0`? You probably don't need all these dynamic code. You could solve it using  an array.

Comment: eval()... out in the wild... what am I SEEING?!?!?!?!?!!?!?!?!!?!?!?!?!?!?!? what is this madness!?

Comment: You could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/nzm7a8ht/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so don't use eval... bad practice, much bugs, little security, unexpected results...

it sounds like you just need an array.

(if you are using a for loop and eval - chances are you really want an array instead).
here is code that does not use eval()

```
reses = [] // of res0, res1 etc
for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    reses[i].replace(`[a${i}]`, window[`a${i}`]);
}
    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        let element =document.getElementById(`a${i}`).value;
    }
```